Photoshop, incline image

I did this years ago. The document on the right was inclined, transformed, result is on the left. It was something simple, but I can't remember what I did. Tried now transform, perspective, skew. Not the desired effect.
Any ideas please?

it's perspective...

No mather how much I try, can't reproduce the results using "transform>perspective". There must be something else. When using perspective is the a key combination or something? (alt, ctrl, shift, so om)

Perspective Transform and then Scale transform the height. You might have to hold Shift when using scale transform to change just the height and not change the width.

It's perspective
and takes 2 steps..

Perspective, which will make the image narrower but leave it the same height.
Then scale vertically to shorten it back to reasonable proportions for the perspective



Thank you. This is it. It appears I had a lot more time for this 10 years ago. Will try again. And if it's too time consuming I will put it on UpWork. Thank you again.

When using Free Transform (Ctrl/Cmd+T), press and hold Ctrl/Cmd. Then pick up one of the corner anchors and move it around. This will allow you to create any possible perspective, even from the side.
Note that once you confirm the transformation, the layer's bounding box will reset to rectangular, so editing the effect isn't easy.
